# Blender Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones error

Tags: modeling, mesh

This error: Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones keeps showing up and I have no idea how to fix it any help?

[image]
[My blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aknm12zf5k39fe2/nightmare%20freddy.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try to fix the geometry first.

Answer (score 0):

The topology is not very good but you can still parent if you want, the problem is that for the moment your object is too small which makes the topology too dense and the calculation too hard. First thing, in *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals, then unparent the head, select both the head and the armature, scale up 10 times (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>10</kbd>) and reparent the head to the armature. Then scale down (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0.1</kbd>), make sure that the scale is applied for the head. It should work.